# Parameter or statistic?

Tags: statistics

> A filling operation is designed to dispense yogurt into plastic cups with an average of 6.1 ounces and standard deviation of 0.05 ounces. Sixteen of the cups of yogurt are selected and carefully weighed resulting in an average fill of 6.02 ounces and a standard deviation of 0.046 ounces. The value 0.046 ounces is a

I think this is a parameter as the experiment is trying to determine the population.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parameter is the actual value of some measurement in the population, while a statistic is a number ( or number-valued function) extracted from  sample data (Edit: most often in order to estimate a population parameter ). Which do you think fits better here?

Answer (score 4):

A parameter would be the average of every single cup of yogurt ever made. In this case, we only know the values of 16 cups of yogurt. Therefore, this is a statistic. The goal of the experiment doesn't matter. In fact, a huge part of the field of statistics is to estimate parameters.